# Unable to include hf/leveldb-android in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, leveldb

I try for hours now to include [hf/leveldb-android](https://github.com/hf/leveldb-android) into an existing android project. To reproduce the issue, just download the project as *.zip file and add it as existing module. So far so god, but if gradle starts build process, it always failed with the following message.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':leveldb:preBuildLevelDB'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'sh''
```

I think is is caused by the following line of code.

```
task preBuildLevelDB {
doLast {
    exec {
        commandLine 'sh', projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + '/src/main/jni-prebuild/prebuild'
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what 'sh' should be for a tool, never heard of it and google doesn't help me out. I tried a few things to modify the gradle.build file, but doesn't solve the issue. Any idea?

Complete gradle.build

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testApplicationId "com.github.hf.leveldb.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    testHandleProfiling true
    testFunctionalTest true
}
}

dependencies {
androidTestCompile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.+'
androidTestCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.6.+'
    }
task preBuildLevelDB {
doLast {
    exec {
        commandLine 'sh', projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + '/src/main/jni-prebuild/prebuild'
    }
    }
    }

preBuild.dependsOn preBuildLevelDB
preBuild {}.mustRunAfter preBuildLevelDB
```

prebuild

```
#!/bin/bash

PREBUILD_DIR=`dirname $0`
PREBUILD_CHECKSUM=`find $PREBUILD_DIR -type f -name "*" -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum`

JNI_DIR=$PREBUILD_DIR/../jni
JNI_LIBS_DIR=$PREBUILD_DIR/../jniLibs

LIBS_DIR=$PREBUILD_DIR/../libs

BUILD_DIR=$PREBUILD_DIR/../../../build
CHECKSUM_FILE=$BUILD_DIR/jni-prebuild-checksum

if [ -f $CHECKSUM_FILE ] && [ -d $JNI_LIBS_DIR ]
  then

  echo $PREBUILD_CHECKSUM | cmp $CHECKSUM_FILE -
  CMP_STATUS=$?

  if [ $CMP_STATUS -eq 0 ]
     then

    echo "Not compiling, sources have not changed."
    exit 0
 fi
fi

rm -f $CHECKSUM_FILE
rm -rf $JNI_DIR
rm -fr $JNI_LIBS_DIR
cp -r $PREBUILD_DIR $JNI_DIR

ndk-build --directory $JNI_DIR

BUILD_STATUS=$?

if [ $BUILD_STATUS -eq 0 ]
  then
  echo $PREBUILD_CHECKSUM > $CHECKSUM_FILE
  cp -r $LIBS_DIR $JNI_LIBS_DIR
fi

rm -rf $JNI_DIR

exit $BUILD_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the `sh` and you can use the `GString` helper methods to simplify the code:

```
task preBuildLevelDB {
    doLast {
        exec {
            // start the execution of the command
            Process process = "${projectDir.getAbsolutePath()}/src/main/jni-prebuild/prebuild".execute()
            // wait for the command to finish then check if successful
            // if we don't explicitly wait the command is executed async from the build
            // this can mean the task ends before the command is finished executing
            if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
                // If the prebuild failed then we probably want to fail the entire build
                throw new Exception("Failed during jni prebuild, check compiler output for error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the solution yet, but on the right path. 'sh' looks like some kind of script. Changed the file extenstion to *.bat (working on an windwos machine) and the script can be executed, but failed on the following line: PREBUILD_CHECKSUM. Think there is some problem in this line. Will update question with the prebuild content.

Comment: You should open a second question on `How to convert unix shell (sh) script to Windows batch (bat) script` Here is some reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script.  I'm guessing its failing on the line `PREBUILD_CHECKSUM=\`find $PREBUILD_DIR -type f -name "*" -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum\``  This is because the commands `find`, `awk`, `sort` and `md5sum` are unix commands to be used by the `Bourne Shell` in unix systems.  You could build in a Cygwin terminal as it makes many bash functions available in a windows environment.

Comment: The second part of your question probably rewrite the `sh` file in `bat` for either `powershell` or `cmd`.  Or build in a Cygwin terminal. Or Build on a unix vm.  Either way the first and second problems are not related

Comment: Jep, I think your totally right. Even your answer is not a "just do this and it works" thing, I showed me the right way, thx.